# Does this follow from second uniqueness theorem in electrostatics?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields

- The second uniqueness theorem states:

> In a volume $V$ surrounded by conductors and containing a specified charge density $\rho$, the electric field is uniquely determined if the total charge on each conductor is given. (The region as a whole can be bounded by another conductor, or else unbounded.)

This means that the two restrictions of $\rho$ and $q$ are enough to give a unique field .

Does it follow then

> If I find an electric field that satisfies the gauss law in differential form (Hence gives correct value of $\rho$) and in integral form (Hence gives correct value of $q$), then that is the solution?

Comment: These two statements are different. In the second statement, the gauss law and the integral form is same thing, connected by divergent theorem. You missed the boudnary condition in the second statement. In the first statement the coductor implicitly given a doundary condition $\vec{E}_{||} = 0$ and $\frac{d\vec E}{dn} = q / \epsilon_o$, a mixed boundary condition.

Comment: What if I add those boundary conditions? Is the second statement correct then?

Comment: I beileve your second equation has  mistakenly substitiuted V for E?

Comment: Yes, you are right; $\vec E\cdot \hat n = q / \epsilon_o$.

Comment: Yes. If you provide the boundary condition, that fulfill the condition for unique theorem.